# Select minimum Seq Num by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Just trying to write a simple query to get the row (per VENDOR_ID) with the minimum `CNTCT_SEQ_NUM` where the `CONTACT_NAME` is not blank.

Here is what I have written:

```
SELECT VENDOR_ID, MIN(CNTCT_SEQ_NUM) AS CNTCT_SEQ_NUM , CONTACT_NAME
FROM PS_VENDOR_CNTCT
WHERE VENDOR_ID IN ('ERSUT', 'MOOREA')
AND CONTACT_NAME <> ''
GROUP BY CONTACT_NAME, VENDOR_ID
```

**Current Results:**

```
VENDOR_ID   CNTCT_SEQ_NUM   CONTACT_NAME
ERSUT       19              V Smith
ERSUT       4               T Peterman
ERSUT       2               I GANCE
ERSUT       8               R FISHER
MOOREA      2               S DALY
MOOREA      4               B SLAUTEN
MOOREA      1               N BLAKELY
```

**Expected results would be:**

```
VENDOR_ID   CNTCT_SEQ_NUM   CONTACT_NAME
ERSUT       2               I GANCE
MOOREA      1               N BLAKELY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT A.* FROM PS_VENDOR_CNTCT A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT VENDOR_ID,MIN(CNTCT_SEQ_NUM) CNTCT_SEQ_NUM
    FROM PS_VENDOR_CNTCT
    GROUP BY VENDOR_ID
)B ON A.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID
AND A.CNTCT_SEQ_NUM = B.CNTCT_SEQ_NUM
```

Comment: Question - Why is this query returning 2 rows? (both have the same EFFDT but one has a MIN CNTCT_SEQ_NUM)      `SELECT VENDOR_ID,MIN(CNTCT_SEQ_NUM) CNTCT_SEQ_NUM, SETID, CONTACT_NAME, EFFDT
    FROM PS_VENDOR_CNTCT
 WHERE CONTACT_NAME <> ''
 AND VENDOR_ID = '05876A'
 GROUP BY VENDOR_ID, SETID, CONTACT_NAME, EFFDT`

Comment: 1 row for ERSUT and 1 row for MOOREA. Its so simple as GROUP BY applied on VENDOR_ID.

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery solves this:

```
select vc.*
from PS_VENDOR_CNTCT vc
where vc.CNTCT_SEQ_NUM = (select min(vc2.CNTCT_SEQ_NUM)
                          from PS_VENDOR_CNTCT vc2
                          where vc2.VENDOR_ID = vc.VENDOR_ID and
                                vc2.CONTACT_NAME <> ''
                         );
```

For performance, you can try an index on `(VENDOR_ID, CONTACT_NAME, CNTCT_SEQ_NUM)`.  This covers the subquery, although all the index records will still need to be scanned.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you do not need `MIN()`, but Window Analytic Function such as `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Q.VENDOR_ID, Q.CONTACT_NAME, Q.CNTCT_SEQ_NUM
  FROM
  (
  SELECT P.*, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                     (PARTITION BY VENDOR_ID ORDER BY CNTCT_SEQ_NUM) AS RN
    FROM PS_VENDOR_CNTCT P
   WHERE VENDOR_ID IN ('ERSUT', 'MOOREA')
     AND CONTACT_NAME <> ''     
   ) Q
  WHERE Q.RN = 1
```

Comment: You only need to partition by VENDOR_ID.